# Reasons\ and Benefits to build SPA application

Tags: javascript, frontend, single-page-application, singlepage

As I understand, SPA means

1. Move maximum of logic to the client. Means client only receive JSON objects from the server by requesting them and nothing else
2. Push all our html to as single page
3. *Maybe something else?*

***Questions***

1. What are reasons/benfits to write Single Page Application?
2. *Especially, what are the benefits to push all our html to a single page?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the big differences with SPAs is responsiveness. They just appear more responsive to the user because there's no gaps while a page has to load. Users can also be given direct feedback while they're waiting for changes (like spinning icons or progress bars). This kind of feedback is well received by users and decreases the perception of wait-time. Users can also be interacting with the app in multiple ways, all without having to wait for a new page load for each interaction.

Comment: So, the main reason is to reduce traffic between client and server, and as a result to increase speed of application?

Comment: And is it impossible to implement progress bar without SPA?

Comment: No, of course not. I mentioned a progress bar as an example feedback mechanism to the user. The feedback helps reduce the user's perceived wait time when ajax requests are doing things in the background.

Comment: Regarding the first question, yes the reduction of traffic between client and server will increase the overall speed/responsiveness of the app because users aren't required to wait for an entire request > response cycle after every interaction. While there'll still be a lot of client/server interaction via ajax, most of this is hidden from the user and doesn't interrupt their experience.

Comment: But what interfere us to us the same AJAX on non spa application. I mean why Single Page? Why not to divide it into many html files?

Comment: Typically an SPA is an MVC (or now more commonly MV*) app. The initial HTML page contains zero or minimal markup. A framework will load views, which populate templates with data from their models. In a sense, the page is divided into many HTML files, but these are in the form of flexible and reusable templates. The templates contain markup and simple view logic (such as loops).